# Is it possible to check current online players in the realm?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there any way (macro, script, addon, command, API method?) to check how many online players are in the realm you're connected to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Census](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/census-plus) addon provides lovely minimalistic graphs/statistics about the realm population (classes, races, lvls, guilds). It does that by performing a series of /who so that it covers the whole population.

Each scan takes about 2 minutes (on my server) and at the end you get a small chat report that is like

> Found 120 new characters and saw 580 existing

From which you can conclude that there are 700 characters online.

Comment: THIS! This is what I was talking about. By the way... On what server do you play? Seems kinda dead to me :)

Comment: Tarren Mill, but numbers are imaginary! Usually we are fewer :]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried /who? I think I remember that working

Edit: I found a simply LOVELY site after some googling: http://wow.realmpop.com/
It looks exactly like what you need. If you need something more than a website, I think this is where my help ends

Comment: Seems like you could do it by changing the default search, based on http://www.wowwiki.com/Who_List

Comment: I've tried /who but it *always* returns 49 players. Tried looking for 10-90 lvl the last time I tried. Any other query I try ends up dumping the same result.

Comment: @Aerocross /who is capped at 50 results. Most 'census' type sites such as the one linked in this answer work by running a large number or queries designed to have minimal overlap and get a number of results under 49. It's a horribly inexact method at best, but the data you want isn't exposed in any other way - presumably by choice.